# Webpacker: Compilation failed: error Command "webpack" not found

Tags: heroku, webpacker, ruby-on-rails-6

Ever since I upgraded to rails 6 and installed webpacker I've been getting this message in production:

```
2019-10-06T10:57:14.221369+00:00 app[web.1]: E, [2019-10-06T10:57:14.221154 #4] ERROR -- : [5e6a4fed-5c09-44fa-a840-24badc9f6a99] [Webpacker] Compilation failed:
2019-10-06T10:57:14.221389+00:00 app[web.1]: error Command "webpack" not found.
```

There are no further details and it appears that all my js is working fine.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
heroku buildpacks:add --index 1 heroku/nodejs
heroku buildpacks:add --index 2 heroku/ruby
```

Per

https://github.com/rails/webpacker/issues/512#issuecomment-309268946

Also,

Yarn should be included on heroku by default ([per this article](https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/1114)) if you have the `webpacker` gem in the Gemfile.